# first order differential equation boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found general solution of this eq:
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=5xy$$

General solution: $$y(x)=e^{5x^2/2+c}$$

Now, i want to check my answer in first eq: $$5xe^{5x^2/2}=5xe^{5x^2/2+c}$$

If $c\neq0$ for some values like y(1)=1, c=-5/2, then equation is incorrect.

Where do I think wrong?

Comment: on the left  side you should have a constant too  $$5.x.e^{5x^2/2+c}=5.x.e^{5x^2/2+c}$$

Comment: The LHS misses a $c$....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {d }{dx}\,e^{5x^2/2+c}=5xe^{5x^2/2+c}$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=5xy(x)$$